# Как получить хэш от произвольного класса для unordered контейнера?

Tags: c++, хеширование

Для того чтобы использовать в качестве ключа собственный класс в `unordered_map` (к примеру) необходимо определить хэш функцию. Пример с cppreference.com

```
template<>
struct hash<S>
{
    typedef S argument_type;
    typedef std::size_t result_type;

    result_type operator()(argument_type const& s) const
    {
        result_type const h1 ( std::hash<std::string>()(s.first_name) );
        result_type const h2 ( std::hash<std::string>()(s.last_name) );
        return h1 ^ (h2 << 1);
    }
};
```

это касается двух полей, меня смущает этот момент `h1 ^ (h2 << 1)` я видел примеры без сдвига и теперь не совсем понимаю как мне проецировать этот пример на большее число полей, по какому правилу. 
Я могу сделать просто `h1 ^ h2 ^ ... ^ h(n)` ? 
или же каждый последующий хэш мне нужно сдвигать? `h1 ^ ( h2 << 1 ) ^ ... ^ ( h(n) << n )`?

Не хотелось бы столкнуться с коллизиями, их будет очень сложно обнаружить, но подпортят работу они значительно.

Comment: С коллизиями Вы неизбежно столкнётесь

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На самом деле, лучше всего стараться «перемешивать» хэшкоды как можно больше. Например, Jon Skeet приводит [такой пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/276994):

```
result_type hash = (result_type)2166136261;
hash = hash * 16777619 ^ std::hash<std::string>()(s.first_name);
hash = hash * 16777619 ^ std::hash<std::string>()(s.second_name);
hash = hash * 16777619 ^ std::hash<std::string>()(s.third_name);
return hash;
```

Код

```
h1 ^ h2 ^ ... ^ h(n)
```

считается неправильным, потому что довольно часто поля имеют *одинаковые* значения и имеют равные хэши (а для целочисленных полей часто в качестве хэша используется само поле). Поскольку при операции `^` равные значения взаимно уничтожаются, то у нас получается меньшее количество хэш-значений и соответственно много коллизий.

Также популярный вариант такой:

```
result_type hash = start;
hash = hash * factor + std::hash<std::string>()(s.first_name);
hash = hash * factor + std::hash<std::string>()(s.second_name);
hash = hash * factor + std::hash<std::string>()(s.third_name);
return hash;
```

(им пользуется Java и .NET) для подходящего значения `start` и `factor`. В качестве `factor` обычно используется небольшое простое число, наподобие 13 или там 29. `start` должно быть по идее взаимно простым с `factor` (например, другое простое число, обычно побольше).

---

Вот хорошая [обзорная статья](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx) (на английском) по различным методикам вычисления хэша.

Answer (score 4):

Вот еще вариант по [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key) с использованием boost

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

struct KeyHasher
{
  std::size_t operator()(const Key& k) const
  {
      using boost::hash_value;
      using boost::hash_combine;

      // Start with a hash value of 0    .
      std::size_t seed = 0;

      // Modify 'seed' by XORing and bit-shifting in
      // one member of 'Key' after the other:
      hash_combine(seed,hash_value(k.first));
      hash_combine(seed,hash_value(k.second));
      hash_combine(seed,hash_value(k.third));

      // Return the result.
      return seed;
  }
};
```